# Terraform, how to generate key/values in map?

Tags: terraform

Terraform, I am trying to generate key/value pairs

```
name1 - net 1-1
name2 - net 1-2
name3 - net 1-3
name4 - net 2-1
```

```
variable "switch_count" {
  type    = number
  default = 2
}  

variable "compute_count" {
  type    = number
  default = 3
} 

locals {
  net_name_switch_compute = {
    for i in range(var.switch_count * var.compute_count) :
      name => flatten([
        for i in range(var.switch_count) : [
          for j in range(var.compute_count) :
          "net-switch-${i+1}-compute-${j+1}"
        ]
      ])
  }
}
```

But I have an error

```
name => flatten([for i in range(var.leaf_count): [for j in range(var.compute_count):"subnet-Leaf-${i+1}-compute-${j+1}"]])

A reference to a resource type must be followed by at least one attribute
access, specifying the resource name.
```

How can i generate key - value pair?